# Android button property animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

How can I animate the property of "layout_alignParentBottom"?

I have a button in a RelativeLayout, I want to animate the button with the property of alignParentBottom.

Following is my code of xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/numbers"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="332dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.56">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#34B9F7"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_number"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#34B9F7"
        android:background="@drawable/button_number"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/num3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_number"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#34B9F7"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/num4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_number"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#34B9F7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

For example, what I want is to make the button whose id is num1 has the property of num2.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) class to animate a button.

If, by *property* you mean *Layout Parameters*, you can set it using the below code.

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setLayoutParams(button2.getLayoutParams());
```